# После загрузки системы спрашивает пароль su

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Установил я себе на ноут Ubuntu 12.04.1. Да вот странность такая, при каждом запуске системы, после полной загрузки, спрашивает пароль для привилегированных действий.

Так вот, как мне найти эту прогу, которая при загрузке системы права себе требует?

Comment: /var/log расскажет омногом

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить, что это обновления пытаются установиться, либо что вероятнее всего монтирование диска происходит коряво, либо какая то программа сохраняет/читает файлы там где не положено - это вероятно должны быть программы настроенные пользователем.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй следующее в `параметрах системы -  управление сеансами`, выбери `Начинать с пустого сеанса`. По идее, при перезагрузке, запустится пустой сеанс, и приложение требующее root не должно загрузиться. Если поможет, то в Управлении сеансами можно вернуть исходное положение.

Также проверь, что имеется в автозагрузке.